# How are named pipes cleaned up on windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous, named-pipes

I am considering using named pipes for debug output from a DLL. My DLL is loaded by a proprietary closed source program which crashes now and then. The problem is that when the program crashes some of my current log output gets lost because windows cleans up everything before it is written to disk.

So my question is if I create a named pipe in a separate process and connect to it from my DLL and the process my DLL is in crashes and is cleaned up will I still be able to read data that was written into the named pipe just before the crash from my second process?

I have to write into the Named pipe in a non blocking (buffered) manor as to affect timing as little as possible, what is the best configuration? Overlapped IO? Can someone give a link to good reading? (I'm not a C++ beginner but I am a WinAPI beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the named pipe buffered data survives the failure of one partner.  Even if you manage to reopen the pipe any data from the old instantiation will be gone.

You could use Memory-Mapped Files (Windows mechanism for interprocess shared memory) instead but you'd have to be careful about handling the state of the shared data space - where to resume writing new data when the process wakes up again?  Some kind of "I've read this far" indication from the sink, maybe.  You'd also have to flush data on write in the source to avoid the problem you recognised with this question, that might make performance subpar but you could test first, tune later.

Comment: thank you, the problem is some insane person decided to make timeouts of 2 milliseconds on some routines so I simply cannot flush any buffers or I cause errors, very frustrating.

Comment: If I initialize a memory mapped file with all \0's which is bigger than my largest expected debug and the source crashes the sink could just read until it encounters a few \0's in a row. All I need is for the data to still be there

Comment: Yes that would work provided you are sure you won't ever see the "end of data" pattern legitimately. Just trying to think of all the issues, what you need depends on the level of robustness desired really. Also what happens if you do overflow the mapped file?  Wrap to beginning after resetting probably, but how much do you reset?

Comment: btw flush to memory-mapped file should be very quick

Comment: I basically just want to document a few crashes to cover my butt and prove my DLL sending bad data is not responsible for the crash. This logging will be remove upon release and really only has  to work on my machine.

Comment: Did you know you can get a full process dump on process exit (normal or otherwise) using Windows Process Dumper.  Using that combined with simpler logging might do the trick

Comment: My favourite little known tool, followed by UMDH.exe for memory leaks